# Scikit-Learn: Labels don't match in Confusion Matrix

Tags: matplotlib, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

Let's say I have an array with (potentially) 43 different values, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
Y_test = pd.Series([4,4,4,42,42,0,1,1,19], dtype=int)
Y_hat = pd.Series([4,4,2,32,42,0,5,5,19], dtype=int)
```

Whenever I try to plot the confusion matrix with:

```
def create_conf_mat(index, y_test, y_hat):
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_hat)
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    cax = ax.matshow(cm)
    plt.title(f'Confusion Matrix ({index} features, 1 outcome)')
    fig.colorbar(cax)
    plt.xlabel('Predicted')
    plt.ylabel('Actual')
    plt.savefig(f'confm_{index}.png')
    plt.savefig(f'confm_{index}.svg')
    plt.savefig(f'confm_{index}.pdf')
    return
```

I don't get the labels [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 19, 32, 42] but [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]. 
I tried to set the labels explicitly by using the unique values in y_test/y_hat as the labels argument but it doesn't work either. I even tried to convert the integer values as strings but by doing so, sklearn complains that at least one label has to be in y_true. 
Does anyone know how I could get the actual values within y_test and y_pred to be plotted as labels within the confusion matrix?

Comment: You can add the following two lines before the return statement `plt.xticks(range(len(y_test)), y_test)` and `plt.yticks(range(len(y_hat)), y_hat)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html), about the `labels` parameter to `confusion_matrix`:

> If None is given, those that appear at least once in y_true or y_pred are used in sorted order.

So, we need to grab together both lists, and extract the list of unique numbers:

```
labels = np.unique(np.concatenate([y_test.values, y_hat.values]))
plt.xticks(range(len(labels)), labels)
plt.yticks(range(len(labels)), labels)
```

[image: result]

Please note that the latest version of 'scikit-learn' now includes an [integrated function to plot a confusion matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html#sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix) with [example code](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-confusion-matrix-py).

Comment: Was this answer helpful?

Comment: That works, thanks a lot! However, the title and the X labels are now overlapping and setting the va/verticalalignment='bottom' does not print the xticks at the bottom of the confusion matrix. Do you know any workaround? :)

Comment: Use something like `plt.title(..., fontsize=..., pad=20)` to control the distance between the title and the x tick labels.  To get the ticks at the bottom, use `ax.xaxis.tick_bottom()`